# Help for solving quadratic residue.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, spoj

I am solving [CRYPTO1](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CRYPTO1/) problem. This problem requires to solve following equation:

$$x^2=q(\mod p)$$

where I am given $p=4,000,000,007$ and q is also given. I followed http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticResidue.html to solve this. I am able to understand Fermat's little Theorem but confused at equation 10 of the given link:

$x=a^{k+1} (\mod p)$     | when $p=4\ast K+3$

Can someone please help me in understanding this part of the equation?

Comment: If $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$, then $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod p$. When $p=4K+3$, we have $(p-1)/2=2K+1$. So
$$(a^{K+1})^2=a^{2K+2}=a^{2K+1}\cdot a\equiv1\cdot a=a\pmod p.$$

Comment: That is because we know that $a\equiv b^2\pmod p$ for some integer $b$ (because $a$ is a QR). The Little Fermat then implies that
$$a^{(p-1)/2}=(b^2)^{(p-1)/2}=b^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks a lot for this explanation, Can't believe I missed such simple thing.

Comment: Don't worry about that. The trick takes most of us by surprise the first time we see it.